# What is the size of the Latex logo in em?

Tags: spacing

So I am trying to put lots of the Latex logo on top of each other, but I don't know the exact size of the logo to move it to the right place.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \newcommand{\latex}{\text{\LaTeX}} % Make the Latex command easier to type
    \newcount\tmp % Dummy counter for the loop
    \newcommand{\latexx}[2]{
        %1 is the distance moved
        %2 is the number of logos to stack
        \tmp=0
        \latex
        \loop
            \advance\tmp by 1
            \hspace{#1 em}\latex
            \ifnum\tmp<#2
        \repeat
    }
\begin{document}
    \[
        \latex
    \]
    \[
        \latexx{-2.566364}{10000}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Zoomed in view of the code.]

This works for stacking them and is pretty close, but as I increase the number stacked you can tell it's not exact.

Does anyone know the exact distance, in em, I need to put in to get them to be indistinguishable from each other?

Comment: Must you have in `em`? Leaving it in `pt` gets me pretty close to perfect, at least to my eyes. `\sbox0{\LaTeX}\the\wd0` gives `25.66368pt`

Comment: Thank you very much! Does that command tell you the width of a box the size of the logo?

Comment: It saves the logo into a box named `0`, and `\the\wd0` prints out the width of the box named `0`, so yes.

Comment: Why not use `\foreach \n in {1,...,1000}{\llap{\LaTeX}}`? This is using [pgffor](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `\sbox0{\LaTeX}\the\wd0` to print out the width of `\latex`. It outputs in `pt`, so I just changed the `em` to `pt` within the loop definition.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\latex}{\text{\LaTeX}} % Make the Latex command easier to type
\newcount\tmp % Dummy counter for the loop
\newcommand{\latexx}[2]{
    %1 is the distance moved
    %2 is the number of logos to stack
    \tmp=0
    \latex
    \loop
    \advance\tmp by 1
    \hspace{#1 pt}\latex
    \ifnum\tmp<#2
    \repeat
}


\begin{document}
    \sbox0{\LaTeX}\the\wd0 % Prints the width of \latex, leave this out of main code

    \[
    \latex
    \]
    \[
    \latexx{-25.66368}{10000}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't one be careful about using specific numbered saveboxes?

Comment: Sure, but I was just using it temporarily. There's no need to keep this line in the actual code

Comment: Perhaps you could add a line to your answer pointing this out...